# How to plot a solution to a difference equation

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I'm trying to plots a graph for a difference equation, so that it plots a graph of X(n) for n=1,2,...,20, here's my code:

```
X(1)=-2;

for n=1:20;
X(n+1) = 0.5 * X(n) + 2;
end
```

I tried to store X(1) to X(20) as vector then plot the graph, however, it didn't work...and I am not sure what I've missed...

Thank you.

Comment: Solved, for somehow if I change the loop from 1:20 to 1:19 and do plot(X) then I got the expected plot, but still don't understand why it should be 19...

Comment: Notice that you want to evaluate 20 values. You already have the first one and you need to evaluate 19 more, thus your loop should iterate 19 times instead of 20. By the way, it should be for n=1:20 without semicolon.

Comment: @Galc127 Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x(1) = -2;
for n = 1:19,  %the comma ',' is not necessary
    x(n+1) = 0.5*x(n) + 2;
end

n=1:20;
plot(n,x)
```

Hope this is helpful and you may try to expand this program.